# Non-standalone Spring Application and SSL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ssl, tomcat

When deploying a Spring Boot application on a separate Tomcat server, where do I have to configure the SSL connection and certificate?
In my "opinion" I have to do that on the Tomcat server and not in the application.properties. Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You configure SSL in `server.xml`

Comment: Very verbose answer ;-)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I tried simple "Yes", but it doesn't pass validation because of its length :)